# How to use AWS KMS for column level encryption on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-kms

Can we use AWS KMS to enable column encryption on SQL Server Database (Web Edition) available.

The Database Server is available on AWS iteself.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What have you tried/researched so far?